# Issue in getting resources directory path programmatically in spring-boot java class throwing an error while running jar with Java -jar

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

In spring boot mvc application I am trying to generate files and store it in a subfolder under resources directory so that I can provide a download link to it to download from UI.
I am able to get the resources directory path using this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("") and its working fine if build and run the project with **mvn clean install spring-boot:run** but if run the jar file with java -jar **.jar then its throwing an error.

How can I make to work with both the things as well as it should work even if I decided to use External Tomcat with out any java class code changes.
By the way I am trying to find out the path in service layer, its pure java class not visibility to servlet.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the result of compiling and packaging your application is either a .jar or a .war file.

Application servers typically expand a .war file, but are not required to do so.

So, you should assume that at runtime, there is no "resource directory".

The safe thing to do is to create a directory yourself (not progamatically), and place the path to that directory in an environment variable to be read by your application.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a working solution for both (IDE/local maven AND a `java -jar`) version with Spring-Boot and Java 8:

```
  final String extension = ".txt";
  final String resourceLocation = "/cool/folder/**/*" + extension ;

  final PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
  final List<String> txtResourceList = new ArrayList<>();
  final Resource[] resources = resolver.getResources( resourceLocation );

  for ( Resource resource : resources ) {
        final String txtFileContent = new BufferedReader(
              new InputStreamReader( resource.getInputStream(),
        StandardCharsets.UTF_8 ) )
        .lines().collect( Collectors.joining( " " ) );
        txtResourceList .add( txtFileContent );
  }
```

Let me know, if something is unclear.